# Detect shift key while already over element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, shift

Is there any way to detect the shift key being pressed while the mouse is already over a particular element?

Right now, what I have is this:

```
$( "body" ).on("mouseover", ".topic:not(.loadable) > p", function ( event ){
    if(event.shiftKey){
        this.style.color = 'goldenrod';
    }
});

$( "body" ).on("mouseleave", ".topic:not(.loadable) > p", function ( event ){
    this.style.color = 'black';
});
```

But it only changes color if the shift key was being held prior to entering the element.

Comment: Wow, duh. Thanks, guys. I'll report back if anything is amiss.

Comment: So I guess it's impossible to detect for shift key presses by themselves?