# Detect key event while mouse over DOM element

Tags: javascript, keydown, mousemove, mouseout

I know how to detect key events on the `document`. I also know how to detect `mousemove` events in a DOM element.

But I don't know how to detect a key event when it happens with the mouse over an element and the mouse it not moving.

I guess I could set a boolean that will set to true by `mousemove` an to false by `mouseout` on the DOM element. But is there a more proper way to do this?

I have found a question that is directly relevant but unanswered (and the comments don't really help):

[Detect shift key while already over element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23208839/1981832)

Comment: Have you tried setting an event listener for a hover over the element, and then having the key press event listener inside the hover event listener?

Comment: If this project is intended for any audience other than yourself, please consider the accessibility implications. This will be an impossible task for screenreaders and non-mouse interfaces. It is also difficult to convey the affordance to the user.

Comment: @JoeFrambach, it's not our place to consider the use case for a question unless it is for something illegal. What if by chance he's trying to use this mechanic for a game, instead of a website? Not everything is always meant to be ***or even can be*** accessible to everyone.

Comment: Hey it's just a comment. In the comments section.

Comment: @RunnyYolk Thanks. I am not sure how to understand your suggestion though. How does one place a listener inside another? I only know how to add a listener to an element.

Comment: @JoeFrambach Thanks. Good point. But I am trying to show a SVG element at the mouse position inside a SVG. It's not for gaming but drawing. So I guess screen readers and non-mouse interfaces don't matter here.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an expansion of my comment above.

Using vanilla JavaScript you can set event listeners on an element for onmouseover and onmouseleave. These event listeners toggle a boolean variable, which is just a flag to say whether the mouse if currently over the element or not.

Then add another event listener on the window for key presses. On key press, if our boolean is true, then run your code, if it's not, do nothing.

```
var mouseOn = false;

document.getElementById('div').onmouseover = function() {
    console.log('mouseover');
    mouseOn = true;
}

document.getElementById('div').onmouseleave = function() {
    console.log('mouseleave');
    mouseOn = false;
}

window.onkeypress = function(e) {
    if(mouseOn == true) {
    console.log(e.key)
  }
}
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wpeLbx9/ (note: the window object in the fiddle is just the panel containing the red square - in order for key presses to be noticed you first have to click on the panel to focus it)

I'm sure my code can be more concise...

Hope that helps!